# Best format to handle Date/Time data received from a DatePicker

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently implementing a `CupertinoDatePicker` , so users can pick an expiredate for an item. I'm using that value and pass it through a constructor to add an item to a ListView.

My questions is, what would be the best format to handle that expiredate.
Using it as a pure string sounds easy, but probably not the best way.
I saw that I can pass it to a `DateTime` , but not sure how convenient that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime works perfect and you can store it as a string no problem.

To decode the string back to datetime simply parse the string:

```
var expireDate = "2019-30-04 00:00"
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(expireDate);
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea, any idea how I can format a DateTime into DD.MM.YYYY ?

Comment: the correct pattern for UTC time is YYYMMDD. ```2012-02-27 13:27:00``` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: Agreed YYYMMDD is the correct pattern but in case you still want to do what you want: formatDate(DateTime.now(), [dd, '/', mm, '/', yyyy, ' ', HH, ':', nn]) with the package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/date_format

Comment: Works perfectly, we're using the DD.MM.YYYY format so its all fine, thanks :)